# slicing in python to reduce dimension

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, slice

Sometimes I see people write code like this (complete code snippet could be found from => http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py),

`some_3_dimensional_list[:, :, 0]`,

I think the purpose of the above code is to remove the last dimension and convert the 3 dimensional list into a 2 dimension list, correct (since `0` means keep nothing)? And wondering if it is the most elegant and efficient way to do so (remove the last dimension)?

```
grd = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimator)
grd_enc = OneHotEncoder()
grd_lm = LogisticRegression()
grd.fit(X_train, y_train)
grd_enc.fit(grd.apply(X_train)[:, :, 0])
grd_lm.fit(grd_enc.transform(grd.apply(X_train_lr)[:, :, 0]), y_train_lr)
```

Comment: `since 0 means keep nothing`... it doesn't, it means take the first 2D slice from a 3D array.

Comment: Note that this is not Python proper, but via the numpy module.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks. I think we mean the same thing. What are the differences between my statement and yours?